# R , Adding Identifiers to a list of Dataframes

Tags: r

I'm working with some data which I've done cleaning on prior to merging . Previously I would have just dealt with each one individually , this time I've tried loading them into a list and formatting them that way.

```
samplenames <- function(x){
x <- gsub("_20220504_cut.csv","",x)
x
}
samplelist <- lapply(fFiles,samplenames)
```

After sub-setting the data I want, I now have a list of 6 tables with the following format.

|  | 3 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GroupCV1 | 1.837566 | 1.38958 | 39.88536 | 1.946550 |
| GroupCV2 | 3.835846 | 7.996139 | 72.67930 | 25.721851 |
| GroupCV3 | 2.384280 | 4.946568 | 60.22007 | 5.670844 |

I've got a list of sample IDs using `gsub` to remove the `.csv` suffix and generate a list of samples in each of the tables

Each of the six tables contains data from one sample in triplicate. My end goal is to get them looking like below before merging

|  | Sample ID | rep | 3 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GroupCV1 | sample1 | sample1a | 1.837566 | 1.38958 | 39.88536 | 1.946550 |
| GroupCV2 | sample1 | sample1b | 3.835846 | 7.996139 | 72.67930 | 25.721851 |
| GroupCV3 | sample1 | sample1c | 2.384280 | 4.946568 | 60.22007 | 5.670844 |

but I am unsure what function I want to use to generate the above table.

Each table contains data from 1 sample with 3 replicates. I assume I need to iterate through the  list of data-frames, and for `fFiles[i]` create `fFiles[i]$Sample` populated with the value from `samplelist[i]`

Too add the rep column I guess I could make a table of the list `(a,b,c)` six times and use the same method ?

Comment: You can identify a list element by its name i.e. `names(lst1) <- seq_along(lst1)`

Comment: `gsub` is vectorized, so you don't need any loop i.e. `samplenames(fFiles)` would be enough

Answer (score 0):

We may use `Map` to create the column

```
Map(function(x, dat) transform(dat, SampleID = x,
    rep = paste0(x, letters[seq_len(nrow(dat))])),
      samplelist, lst1)
```

Comment: Thank you ! This worked perfectly , I've not come across `Map` before. I think I need to look into it to understand what's going on.